# customizing adapters for ember api actions

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am referring ember api actions: https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions

Wanted to ask, does someone know if i have an adapter for the model itself but I want to customize the adapter only for one of the member action defined, is it possible to do so?

For example, if my model looks like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  userName: attr('string');
  withdrawMoney: memberAction({path: 'actions/withdraw', type: 'POST'})
})
```

Now adapter for my user model has some headers set. But what I want to do now is if I invoke my member action, then I want to add additional headers. Is it possible to do so without impacting headers globally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I found the answer by reading the source here:
https://github.com/mike-north/ember-api-actions/blob/master/addon/utils/member-action.js#L11

```
withdrawMoney: memberAction({
  path: 'actions/withdraw',
  type: 'POST',
  ajaxOptions: {
    headers: {
      // ...
    }
  }
}),
```

Please note this is not documented and I have not tested this out.